# IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory MongoDB in Windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, configure

**I was getting this error when I was trying to change my dbpath**

```
mongod --dbpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\db"
```

Comment: check this out [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42447303/11089768) and if you are on windows check this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59432890/11089768)

Answer (score 4):

**I fixed it in 2 ways:**

**First**, using cmd as an administrator then it worked

**Second**, changing my drive to some other drive.

```
mongod --dbpath "D:\MongoDB Self\db"
```

If you have any other solutions please let me know.