# MongoDB (Docker) Error 20 - IllegalOperation while trying to start transaction

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm using MongoDB docker (4.4.x) image as my DB for NestJS backend. One of the API is triggered by a webhook of my payment gateway. Since its a payment related DB ops, I use transactions for ACID. The problem is, after I start session, then transaction & try to find one document (the very first query in the transaction), It throws an error :

```
{
  "ok": 0,
  "code": 20,
  "codeName": "IllegalOperation",
  "name": "MongoError"
}
```

I then switched to the MongoDB Atlas dev server and the whole transaction works flawlessly. Which leads me to believe that, there is something wrong with my installation of mongo docker image.

My docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    database:
        image: 'mongo'
        container_name: 'mongoDbDev'
        environment:
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=789512346
        volumes:
            - ./mongo-volume:/data/db
        ports:
            - '27017:27017'
```

The `mongo-volume` directory is located in `~/Documents/Workspace/Docker/mongodb/`

I tried [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42446931/mongodb-exception-in-initandlisten-20-attempted-to-create-a-lock-file-on-a-rea) solution but did not work. Which TLDR; Changing permissions to the `./mongo-volume` folder.

Additional info,

1. I user docker-compose command without sudo (tried with sudo, did not
   work)
2. I have to use docker with sudo command, [post installation steps](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/) did not work for me

Comment: Hey @wetidod701 Mongo ACID Trxns will work on MongoDB Sharded clusters or replica sets, can you try creating a replica set? Also the server you connect through Mongodb Atlas is it a cluster you're connecting to? Thanks.

Comment: I'm using a standalone mongoDB docker instance and I think, yes, I'm using the M0 free tier MongoDB Atlas Cluster (is free tier a cluster?) as dev server. So all I gotta do is create a replica set?

Comment: Indeed, you can refer to the docs for [Transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/).

Comment: Oh thanks, It completely went over my head. I'll check it out.